# Run Draw SVG use CSS

Tags: javascript, css, svg, drawing

i have SVG path, and i want to make draw animation for this SVG like "CROSS"....

so could you help me guys,...?

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" class="logo-cross" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="50%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 63.7 64.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 63.7 64.7;" xml:space="preserve">
 <style type="text/css">
 <![CDATA[.st0{fill:#929396;}.st1{fill:#F00;}]]>
 </style>
 <g>
 <path class="st0" d="M1.3,1h3.5L1.3,4.5V1z M1.3,8.7L9,1h4.2L1.3,12.9V8.7z M1.3,54.7L55.1,1h-4.2L1.3,50.5V54.7z M1,63.1L63.1,1
    h-4.2L1,58.9V63.1z M1.3,21.2L21.6,1h-4.2l-16,16V21.2z M1.3,46.3L46.7,1h-4.2L1.3,42.2V46.3z M1.3,38l37-37h-4.2L1.3,33.8V38z
    M1.3,29.6L29.9,1h-4.2L1.3,25.4V29.6z"/>
 <path class="st1" d="M1,59.6l3.5,3.5H1V59.6z M1,55.4l7.7,7.7h4.2L1,51.2V55.4z M1,13.6l49.5,49.5h4.2L1,9.4V13.6z M1,5.2
   l57.9,57.9h4.2L1,1V5.2z M1,47.1l16,16h4.2L1,42.9V47.1z M1,21.9l41.2,41.2h4.2L1,17.7V21.9z M1,30.3l32.8,32.8H38l-37-37V30.3z
  M1.3,38.7l24.4,24.4h3.9L1,34.5L1.3,38.7z"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the D3 library as it will help you tremendously.

Comment: Sorry ... D3 library..?

what is that sir..?

Comment: http://d3js.org/. This is a really complicated problem and would take more explanation than I can post here.

Comment: Thanks for your participant sir..
this is demo link in JSFIDDLE

https://jsfiddle.net/az410jry/2/